# Add a calendar to android app, marking certain events

Tags: java, android, calendar

I want to do this using user input and display it in a calendar format. Any source code or direction to a tutorial will help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html) and [working with a Calender](http://www.developer.com/ws/article.php/3850276/Working-with-the-Android-Calendar.htm) are both good reads.

Comment: thanks for the links, but I was thinking more along the lines of a CalendarView that I could display in my own layout... as I said, one possibility would be to use CalendarView, rather than the phone's calendar..

Comment: In that case,you could probably just use the [CalenderView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView.html)'s constructor to pass in attributes for style. Otherwise, the best bet might be to stick with Google's Calender, as linked in the other answer by Femi

Answer (score 0):

Try this for an Android view that provides a ready to go calendar display: http://code.google.com/p/android-calendar-view/

EDIT: to see usage, look at http://code.google.com/p/android-calendar-view/wiki/HowToUse and for a code sample, look at http://code.google.com/p/android-calendar-view/source/browse/trunk/src/com/exina/android/calendar/CalendarActivity.java .

Comment: I have seen this as well, but I cannot figure out how to add this to my existing program, nor how to mark certain dates. Could you give me some sample code/ help on how to do that?